# How to route WiFi traffic to another box?

Tags: networking, wifi, routing

When I want to route the ethernet traffic to another host, so that I can do natting and/or proxying, I can change the default gw with either `ip route` or `route` commands.

Can I accomplish the same but for WiFi traffic? If yes, how?

I tried with `ip route add default via 192.168.2.123 dev wlan0` command, but it has no effect.

I'm running this command on an embedded device with Android which only has a wifi connection.

The address of `192.168.2.123` is the address of my linux box that has 2 network interfaces: one wifi (the address above) and one ethernet which I use to access internet.

Comment: Yes for IP traffic (rather than "Ethernet"). But without a detailed explanation of your setup, it's not possible to know one of several possible reasons it won't work as you would like it works. This question also involves the router in addition to the Linux system, by the way.

Comment: Make sure you have enabled ip forwarding.  You can check with `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`.  Have you thought about you are going to tell other machines to use this route?

Comment: @A.B I've updated with more details. Does that help?

@ARF on which box? The problem is that once I set the default gateway, I would expect at least the device to stop reaching the network if forwarding was not enabled. But instead the device keeps accessing the network.

I assume  the Mac address of the device with `192.168.2.123` would be used in all Wifi packets after I set that as gateway. Is my assumption correct? Thanks.